# Is there something like block_field?

Tags: entities, blocks

I need to be able to include block in the content of a node. I use display suite to accomplish this, but just wondering if is there something like block_field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the http://drupal.org/project/blockreference.  It's a standard on our projects now.  It also works well with the http://drupal.org/project/bean module

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered [this module](http://drupal.org/project/insert_block) which lets you insert a block directly into content via a `[block]` tag.

If you prefer the field way, I think display suite is the way to go, which is hat you did already.

Maybe [CCK blocks](http://drupal.org/project/cck_blocks) could be of use, but as it is, I'm not sure what use case you're trying to cover so maybe it's OT.

Comment: The http://drupal.org/project/insert_block module looks fine. I'll try it. cck_blocks allows you to put a field content outside the main content of the node.